# Can't get phonegap to build android app fullscreen

Tags: android, html, xml, fullscreen, phonegap

I'm trying to build an app with `Phonegap` desktop onto the Phonegap develepor app. I need the app to be fullscreen so I have made sure this is in my `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

I've tested on 2 different android devices (OnePlus 3T and Samsung A3) and the status bar still shows up on both. I've tried with a blank template that I put my own code into and with the 'Hello World' template which has the preference already enabled in it's config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't to do with the fullscreen preference being set incorrectly, but the `config.xml` file not being read/sent. Refer to [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219628/config-xml-not-being-read-sent-when-building-from-phonegap-desktop)