# config.xml not being read/sent when building from phonegap desktop

Tags: android, html, xml, phonegap

I'm trying to build an app with phonegap desktop and the developer app. Everything seems to be working apart from the preferences I've set in the `config.xml` file. I've set:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" /> 
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"/>
```

However the app always build with the status bar at the top of the screen and the orientation acting as if there has been no preference set.

I've tried on a OnePlus 3T and a Samsung A3, both having the same issues. I assume this is because `config.xml` ins't being read?

I've tried using the `Hello World` template in Phonegap desktop that has orientation and fullscreen preferences enabled and it still doesn't work. I have also tried moving the file inside the www/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that using Phonegap desktop/app doesn't utilise the `config.xml` file in any way. Using Phonegap build does however, so I'm now using that instead.